# voltage polarity, current polarity, problem Overleaf circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I have a problem whit Overleaf..

When wanting to change the polarity of a voltage or current, I get an error.
I have tried a latex executable compiler, and it works fine. The problem is in OverLeaf.

```
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1,transform shape]
    \draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {};
    \draw (opamp.+)to[R,a=$R_4$,i^=\footnotesize$I_{R_{_{34}}}$]++(0,-2.5)node[ground]{};
    \draw (opamp.+)to[open]++(-3,0)coordinate(v1);
    \draw (v1) node[anchor=south east,]{$v_2$}
           to[R,o-*,a=$R_3$,](opamp.+);
    \draw (opamp.-)to[R,*-o,l_=$R_1$,i_<=\footnotesize $I_{R_{_{1}}}$,v_=          
     $V_{R_{_{1}}}$,voltage shift = 6]++(-3,0)node[anchor= south east,]{$v_1$}; %HERE THE PROBLEM%
    \draw (opamp.-)|-++(0,2)to[R,l=$R_2$,i_=\footnotesize$I_{R_{_{2}}}$,
           v^<=$V_{R_{_{2}}}$,voltage shift=5]++(2.25,0)-|(opamp.out);
           %HERE THE PROBLEM%
    \draw (opamp.out)to[short,*-o]++(1,0)node[above]{$v_o$};
    \draw (opamp.up)--++(0,0.4)node[vcc]{$V_{_{CC}}$};
    \draw (opamp.down)--++(0,-0.4)node[vee](VEE){$V_{_{EE}}$};
    \path (opamp.-) \coord($v_a$);
    \path (opamp.+) \coord($v_b$);
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

VR2?? IR1????
**The error is that it does not let me put, example: "v_>" or "v_ <".  It works fine in TexMaker, but not in Overleaf. I hope it was better understood**
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your circuit scheme. The problem not seems to be in Overlief but in your code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because OP claims cannot be confirmed nor with test with local LaTeX installation nor with use of Overleaf service.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear, what a result you expect. After clearing-up your code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[font=\footnotesize]
\draw   ( 0,0)      node[op amp] (opamp) {} 
        (opamp.+)   to [R,a=$R_4$,i^=$I_{R_{34}}$] ++ (0,-2) node[ground]{}
        (opamp.+)   to [open] ++ (-3,0) %coordinate(v1);
                    node [left]    {$v_2$}
                    to [R,l_=$R_3$,i_<=$I_{R_3}$, o-*] (opamp.+) 
        (opamp.-)   to [R,a=$R_1$,i_<=$I_{R_1}$, 
                                  v_>=$V_{R_1}$, voltage shift=4, o-*] ++ (-3,0)
                    node[ left] {$v_1$}
        (opamp.-)   --  ++ (0,2) coordinate (aux)
                    to [R=$R_2$, i_=$I_{R_2}$,
                                 v^<=$V_{R_2}$, voltage shift=4] (aux -| opamp.out)
                    to [short,-*] (opamp.out)
    (opamp.out)     to[short,-o] ++ (1,0) node[right]{$v_o$}
% supply
        (opamp.up)   -- ++ (0,0.4) node[vcc] {$V_{CC}$}
        (opamp.down) -- ++ (0,-0.4)node[vee] {$V_{EE}$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

the above MWE (Minimal Working Example) gives the following result:

[image]

Tested on PC with recent 64-bit MikTeX installation as well with Overleaf service. Overleaf service gets a *warnings* that you need to specify `nooldvoltagedirection` option when loading `circuitikz` package (see second example).

**Edit:** Confirmation, that provided solution works also with voltage drops on resistors in opposite direction:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[nooldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[font=\footnotesize]
\draw   ( 0,0)      node[op amp] (opamp) {} 
        (opamp.+)   to [R,a=$R_4$,i^=$I_{R_{34}}$] ++ (0,-2) node[ground]{}
        (opamp.+)   to [open] ++ (-3,0) %coordinate(v1);
                    node [left]    {$v_2$}
                    to [R,l_=$R_3$,i_<=$I_{R_3}$, o-*] (opamp.+) 
        (opamp.-)   to [R,a=$R_1$,i_<=$I_{R_1}$, 
                                  v_<=$V_{R_1}$, voltage shift=4, *-o] ++ (-3,0)
                    node[ left] {$v_1$}
        (opamp.-)   --  ++ (0,2) coordinate (aux)
                    to [R=$R_2$, i_=$I_{R_2}$,
                                 v^>=$V_{R_2}$, voltage shift=4] (aux -| opamp.out)
                    to [short,-*] (opamp.out)
    (opamp.out)     to[short,-o] ++ (1,0) node[right]{$v_o$}
% supply
        (opamp.up)   -- ++ (0,0.4) node[vcc] {$V_{CC}$}
        (opamp.down) -- ++ (0,-0.4)node[vee] {$V_{EE}$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With both solution uses `v_>`, `v_<` and are tested in Overleaf services. In Overleaf services you get warnings (*not an error*) that you need to specify `nooldvoltagedirection` in `circuitikz` package options (see the second example). They works as expected and gives showed results.

Comment: Hi, Zarco! Thanks, but the error is that it does not let me put, example: "v_>" or "v_ <".  It works fine in TexMaker, but not in Overleaf. I hope it was better understood

Comment: @MatiasTevez, do you like to have voltage `$V_{R_1}$`  `$V_{R_2}$` in opposite direction as they are now in my solution? I haven't any problem with change it in local installation as well in Overleaf.

Comment: no, I want to have it like this!  but it doesn't compile it by the "v ^ <".  That's the problem.

Comment: @MatiasTevez, as you can see from my MWE, that this works as expected, so I can't confirm your claims.

Comment: It is perfect, but not in overleaf.  It doesn't matter, thanks for everything and sorry for the inconvenience, Zarco!

Comment: @MatiasTevez,(i) I9m Zarko, not Zarco :-), /ii( It works in Overleaf too (Tested).

Comment: I'm sorry, Zarko! Thanks for everything!!